# .split() JS not "splitting" correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I've got the following string:

```
str = "data1 data2 data3";
```

And I want to convert it to an array doing the following:

```
list = str.split(",");
```

But when I run this:

```
alert(list[1]);
```

…it does not retrieve "data2". And when I call this:

```
alert(data[0]);
```

¬it retrieves "data1, data2, data3".

Is there something wrong? I want to access the different words from the string by calling them from the number (0,1,2 - in this case) instead of all of them going to list[0]

Comment: there's no `,` in `str`, how can there be `,` in `data[0]` - you're misrepresenting the input or output I feel ... and how is `data` array even being created?

Comment: `list = str.split(" ");` if you had `str = "data1,data2,data3";` then your solution would work

Comment: I see no assignment to `data` .. you're not posting the whole story

Comment: sorry, i meant alert(list[0]);  but i solved it already, thanks anyway everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separator you are using in the `split` method is comma(`,`). But your input string does not have a comma, but it has spaces between words. So you need to split with space as the operator.

```
list = str.split(" ");
```

When separator is found, it is removed from the string and the substrings are returned in an array. If separator is not found, the array contains one element consisting of the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to split using "," as a separator. You will have to use:

```
list = str.split(" ");
```

It'll work that way ;)